# Java Создание Jar архива

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

Создал проект использующий JavaFX и fxml графический интерфейс. и хотел бы создать jar архив, чтобы скинуть кому-нибудь мою прогу - первый тестовый проект - калькулятор.
[image: проект]

Мой код
https://pastebin.com/kUGexBZE
Вообщем когда создаю jar через экспорт в eclipse выводит warning сборка с ошибкой компиляции. jar создается, но не запускается

[image: ошибка]

Comment: можещь скинуть полностью проект? https://www.zipshare.com/

Comment: не знаю как это сделать

Comment: https://file.io/L9adjp ну вроде бы

Comment: используйте maven  для сборки, его достаточно скачать с сайта, распаковать, указать в системе адрес к папке bin. Добавить в проект файл pom.xml заполнить его и попросить мавен собрать =) Пока писал, понял что действий на вид много, но по факту все делается за 3-5 минут.

Comment: Все я решил вопрос